# Can assignment change value of floating point number?

Tags: floating-point, jvm

I know that comparing floating point numbers with equality is a bad idea. My question is if it is safe to compare numbers which come from the same computation. E.g. (java code)

```
double doSomething(double d) {
    return d;
}

void test() {
    double result = computation();
    double result2 = result;
    Double result3 = new Double(result)
    Double result4 = new Double(result2)
    double result5 = doSomething(result2)
    //etc.
    //now do all of the above compare equal? i.e.
    boolean b = result4.doubleValue() == result //is this true?
    //and for other combinations?
}
```

It seems they should be equal, but I'm not sure if it is really true because of FPU registers. Does JVM guarantee that they are equal? And a bonus question: How about C?

Sorry if this was answered before, I wasn't able to find an answer.

Comment: C definitely does not guarantee this. One may be in a register and another may be in memory, which can use different precisions.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: C requires that assignment round a value to the nominal type of the destination. Only intermediate values may be computed with extra precision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both Java and C require that assignment convert the assigned value to the destination type with no extra precision or range. Further simple assignment then cannot change the value.

In [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/jls7.pdf), this is specified in 5.1.13 (Value Set Conversion) and 5.2 (Assignment Conversion).

In [C 2011 (N1570)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), this is mentioned in 5.2.4.2.2 9.

Comment: Thank you for the references